Have I correctly derived the iterative updates for weighted least squares?
I have an exercise where I have to derive the both $w_i^{(m-1)}$ and $z_i^{(m-1)}$ from the iterative weighted least squared updating equation $b^{(m)} = \left( X^\top W^{(m-1)} X \right)^{-1} X^\top W^{(m-1)} z^{(m-1)}$ for the BeetleMortality data with the probit link $\phi$. Then I have to implement it in R. From what I understand, $w_i^{(m-1)}=\frac{1}{\text{Var}(Y)} (\frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial \eta_i}) ^2 = \frac{\phi'(\eta_i)^{(m-1)}}{n\mu_i^{(m-1)}(1 - \mu_i^{(m-1)})}$ and $z_i^{(m-1)} = \eta_i^{(m-1)} (y_i -\mu_i) \frac{\partial \eta_i}{\partial \mu_i}= \eta_i^{(m-1)} + \frac{y_i + \mu_i^{(m-1)}}{\phi'(\eta_i)^{(m-1)}}$ where $\phi'$ is the normal distribution PDF. I have implemented this in R, where I am pretty sure everything in the implementation is correct. Therefore I am lead to belief that the problem is in how I have derived these values. Did I make any mistake? I am relatively new to all this so it could very well be that I made some glaring mistake which I cannot find. Any feedback is appreciated!

Assuming that each $Y_i$ is a(n independent) binomial proportion s.t. $n_i \cdot Y_i \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(n_i, \mu_i)$, and adopting your notation, we have $\mu_i^{(m-1)} = \phi\Big(\eta_i^{(m-1)}\Big)$.
Hence,
$$
\frac{\partial \mu_i^{(m-1)}}{\partial \eta_i^{(m-1)}} 
= \phi'\Big(\eta_i^{(m-1)}\Big),
$$
and the working weights are given by
\begin{aligned}
w_i^{(m-1)}
&= \frac{1}{\operatorname{Var}(Y_i)\big|_{\mu_i = \mu_i^{(m-1)}}} \left(\frac{\partial \mu_i^{(m-1)}}{\partial \eta_i^{(m-1)}}\right)^2 \\
&= \frac{\Big[\phi'\Big(\eta_i^{(m-1)}\Big)\Big]^2}{\mu_i^{(m-1)} \Big(1 - \mu_i^{(m-1)}\Big) / n_i}.
\end{aligned}
Since $\eta_i^{(m-1)} = \phi^{-1}\Big(\mu_i^{(m-1)}\Big)$, the inverse function theorem gives
$$
\frac{\partial \eta_i^{(m-1)}}{\partial \mu_i^{(m-1)}} = \frac{1}{\phi'\Big(\eta_i^{(m-1)}\Big)}.
$$
With that, the working observations can be written as
\begin{aligned}
z_i^{(m-1)} 
&= \eta_i^{(m-1)} + \left(y_i - \mu_i^{(m-1)}\right) \frac{\partial \eta_i^{(m-1)}}{\partial \mu_i^{(m-1)}} \\
&= \eta_i^{(m-1)} + \frac{y_i - \mu_i^{(m-1)}}{\phi'\Big(\eta_i^{(m-1)}\Big)}.
\end{aligned}

R Code
data("BeetleMortality", package = "glmx")

m_1 <- glm(cbind(died, n - died) ~ dose, data = BeetleMortality, 
           family = binomial(link = "probit"))
beta_1 <- coef(m_1)

beta_2 <- rep(0, length(beta_1))
X <- model.matrix(m_1)
y <- m_1$y
n <- m_1$prior.weights

n_iter <- 20
for (i in seq_len(n_iter)) {
  eta <- X %*% beta_2
  mu <- pnorm(eta)
  phi_prime <- dnorm(eta)
  w <- c(phi_prime^2 / (mu * (1 - mu) / n))
  z <- eta + (y - mu) / phi_prime
  # numerically stable computation (less stable, "naive" alternative below)
  beta_2 <- coef(lm.fit(x = sqrt(w) * X, y = sqrt(w) * z))
  # W <- diag(w)
  # beta_2 <- solve(t(X) %*% W %*% X) %*% t(X) %*% W %*% z
}

all.equal(beta_1, beta_2)
# [1] "Mean relative difference: 1.988909e-07"

